# PHP Fatal error: Interface 'JsonSerializable'

Tags: php, json, apache, lamp, magento2

I'm trying to install Magento2 on a new server LAMP setup. I am running the following:

- Ubuntu Server 16.04
- PHP 7.0
- Apache 2.4

I keep getting a 500 error and when I refer to the logs I can see `PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'JsonSerializable' Not Found`.

I have tried running `apt-get install php-json` and restarting Apache but this doesn't work. I have also tried enabling JSON using `a2enmod json` but i get an error saying the module doesn't exist.

I have been as far as page 3 on Google and found nothing that helps. Can anyone come up with something that I haven't already? I am officially at a loss.

Comment: What OS are you running and what version? I would normally expect the command to be `sudo apt-get install php7.0-json`

Comment: @ShiraNai7 I am positive I am running PHP 7 `php -v` shows `PHP 7.0.7-4+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )`

Comment: @JonStirling I have update my question with OS. I tried `php7.0-json` too. It says it's already installed

Comment: If you're on 16.04, then why are you using deb.sury.org? That might be where the problem is.

Comment: @JonStirling I think you have found where my knowledge ends! Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: You wouldn't be the first one who runs one PHP version in the command line and another one in Apache. Loading a file with `<?php phpinfo();` through Apache is probably a better test than running `php -v` in the command line. (BTW, I believe the `a2enmod` command enables **Apache** modules, not PHP extensions.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález from `phpinfo()`: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc/php/7.0/apache2`. And I know `a2enmod` is for apache, it was mentioned on 1 of the 3 Google pages of research :)

Comment: PHP version is the first line in `phpinfo()`'s output. Whatever, I suppose it's correct or you'd had mentioned it. Can you see a **json** table? Is `json_encode()` unavailable or just `JsonSerializable`? What happened when you typed `apt-get install php-json`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález JSON is only mentioned in phpinfo() under Module Authors. `json_encode` produces a 500 error: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function json_encode()`

Comment: Then it's clear that the entire JSON feature is unavailable. If `apt-get install php-json` actually succeeded, it either updated the wrong installation or there was some other error afterwards. Sorry but my experience with Ubuntu is close to zero, I don't have further suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get around this issue by simply purging everything PHP and reinstalling. I used `sudo apt-get install php` rather than specifying a version and it installed the exact same version as before.

What is odd is that everything seems to be exactly the same as it was only this time it works.

I suppose these things are sent to try us...